# What is the easiest way to prepare a Glauber coherent state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Without using a laser source. Can you, for example, create a coherent state by filtering another light source (incandescent light bulb, LED, etc)?

Comment: Coherent state of *what*? Light? Electrical signals? We can guess from the examples in this post that you're interested in light, but it's not obvious whether or not you'd accept an answer relating to a different physical system.

Comment: I used light as an example because it is easy to create and cheap to buy.  Ideally, I would like an answer that does not include lasers, BECs, or superconductors. It does not have to involve light.

Comment: I would say that every "classical" electronic oscillator is in such a state. Dial down the temperature and the amplitude and you are getting ever closer to a "quantum coherent state". The difficulty is NOT in generating such a state but in the diagnostics of it. You will simply be swamped by noise when you are trying to detect it. I would almost say that your question is ill-defined.

Comment: To expand on CuriousOne's example: Even the classical motion of a mechanical pendulum (decoupled from the environment) can be though of as being a coherent state (remember, that coherent states can be understood as the classical limit of free bosonic theories).

Answer (score 0):

Bose-Einstein *condensates* as well as *superconductive* materials could be utilized to produce such coherent states. So, the answer would be, "I don't think filtering light sources would be an efficient way of producing coherent sources."

A quantum *dot* trapped inside a *quadratic potential,* (namely a quantum harmonic oscillator,) is the only practical example I can think of at the moment. But, I believe experimental solid state or condensed matter physicists should give you practical implementation of such coherent states.

Comment: I understand that superconductors, BECs and lasers can produce coherent states. But I am trying to understand whether there exists other ways  of creating coherent states.